# GLMM for percentage response variable

Tags: r, proportion, glmm, percentage

I have a completely randomized block design with 4 treatments and 3 replicates per treatment (12 parcels). Each replicate is placed within a block.
In each parcel I have measured the number of infested leaves and the total amount of leaves at different times in the year. The total number of leaves is not equal among parcels. I want to test whether there are differences on the proportion of infested leaves among treatments considering that I have repeated measures in time of the same plants and a blocking factor.

Alternatively, I am interested in knowing whether the variation in the proportion (proportion of the last sampling minus proportion of the first sampling) Is different among treatments.

Which approach do you suggest me? Which test is more appropriate considering the two options?

Edit 19/02/2024:
Following the received advices, I include the info on the dataset:

```
'data.frame':   2645 obs. of  18 variables:
 $ ID_pianta                : chr  "_Pianta_1S3C" "_Pianta_2S3C" "_Pianta_3S3C" "_Pianta_4S3C" ...
 $ Data_rilievo             : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Coltura                  : chr  "Spinacio" "Spinacio" "Spinacio" "Spinacio" ...
 $ Nome_parcella            : chr  "S3C" "S3C" "S3C" "S3C" ...
 $ Blocco                   : num  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ Trattamento              : chr  "Controllo" "Controllo" "Controllo" "Controllo" ...
 $ Infestate                : num  0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ Totale_foglie            : num  5 5 5 4 6 3 5 9 6 6 ...
 $ Numero_foglie_minate     : num  0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 3 0 ...
 $ Percentuale_foglie_minate: num  0 0.2 0 0 0 ...
 $ N_mine_serpentina        : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ N_mine_macchia           : num  NA 1 NA NA NA 1 NA NA 3 NA ...
 $ Totale mine              : num  NA 1 NA NA NA 1 NA NA 3 NA ...
 $ Foglie_sane              : num  5 4 5 4 6 2 5 9 3 6 ...
 $ log_Numero_foglie_minate : num  0 0.693 0 0 0 ...
 $ log_Foglie_sane          : num  1.79 1.61 1.79 1.61 1.95 ...
```

and also some informative plots
Percentage mined leaves among treatments:

```
library(flexplot)
flexplot(Percentuale_foglie_minate~Trattamento,spread="quartiles", jitter=c(.1, 0), data = data_infestate)
```

[image: Percentage mined leaves]

Distribution of mined leaves:

```
flexplot(Numero_foglie_minate~1, data = data_infestate)
```

[image: Distribution of mined leaves]

Then, I applied the following model to test whether the infested leaves "Numero_foglie_minate" and the healthy leaves "Foglie_sane" differ among treatments

**MODEL 1**

```
   summary(model_interazione)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: cbind(Numero_foglie_minate, Foglie_sane) ~ Trattamento + Blocco +      Data_rilievo + (1 | ID_pianta)
   Data: data_infestate
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e+05))

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  4066.1   4142.5  -2020.0   4040.1     2632 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.6876 -0.4813 -0.3308  0.1900  4.8004 

Random effects:
 Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID_pianta (Intercept) 1.307    1.143   
Number of obs: 2645, groups:  ID_pianta, 478

Fixed effects:
                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)          -2.98258    0.18485 -16.135  < 2e-16 ***
TrattamentoLavanda   -0.43253    0.19115  -2.263   0.0237 *  
TrattamentoRosmarino -0.40539    0.20356  -1.992   0.0464 *  
TrattamentoTimo      -0.22146    0.18686  -1.185   0.2360    
Blocco2              -0.33823    0.17387  -1.945   0.0517 .  
Blocco3              -0.04462    0.17187  -0.260   0.7951    
Data_rilievo9         0.03357    0.12291   0.273   0.7848    
Data_rilievo16       -0.01192    0.12264  -0.097   0.9226    
Data_rilievo22        0.08879    0.12123   0.732   0.4639    
Data_rilievo29       -0.03263    0.12380  -0.264   0.7921    
Data_rilievo36       -0.32984    0.12850  -2.567   0.0103 *  
Data_rilievo52       -0.56837    0.12778  -4.448 8.67e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) TrttmL TrttmR TrttmT Blocc2 Blocc3 Dt_rl9 Dt_r16 Dt_r22 Dt_r29 Dt_r36
TrttmntLvnd -0.468                                                                      
TrttmntRsmr -0.411  0.463                                                               
TrattamntTm -0.512  0.495  0.463                                                        
Blocco2     -0.441 -0.034 -0.127  0.018                                                 
Blocco3     -0.436 -0.057 -0.153 -0.002  0.546                                          
Data_riliv9 -0.324 -0.007  0.046 -0.007 -0.046 -0.044                                   
Data_rilv16 -0.331 -0.004  0.044 -0.003 -0.040 -0.039  0.539                            
Data_rilv22 -0.329 -0.009  0.037 -0.016 -0.043 -0.040  0.546  0.551                     
Data_rilv29 -0.326 -0.003  0.039 -0.015 -0.041 -0.041  0.536  0.542  0.553              
Data_rilv36 -0.317  0.004  0.047 -0.003 -0.041 -0.046  0.515  0.519  0.531  0.531       
Data_rilv52 -0.318  0.001  0.046 -0.010 -0.038 -0.036  0.520  0.525  0.536  0.540  0.518
```

Seems there are significant effects for treatments and also for the last sampling dates. I have used the package `DHARMa` for some diagnostics and this is what I get:

```
> library(DHARMa)
> # Simulate standardized residuals
> simulated_residuals <- simulateResiduals(model_interazione)
> # Plot diagnostic plots
> plot(simulated_residuals)
```

[image: Residuals analysis]

Edit 20/02/2024

Following suggestions, I add the results of the `glmer` with interaction between treatment and time. I had to increase the number of interactions to eliminate convergence issues:

**MODEL 2**

```
    > model_interazione <- glmer(cbind(Numero_foglie_minate, Foglie_sane) ~ Trattamento*Data_rilievo + Blocco + (1 | ID_pianta),
+                            data = data_infestate,family=binomial, 
+                            glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000)))
> summary(model_interazione)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: cbind(Numero_foglie_minate, Foglie_sane) ~ Trattamento * Data_rilievo +      Blocco + (1 | ID_pianta)
   Data: data_infestate
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e+05))

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  4070.8   4253.1  -2004.4   4008.8     2614 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.6316 -0.4806 -0.3263  0.1601  4.4388 

Random effects:
 Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID_pianta (Intercept) 1.313    1.146   
Number of obs: 2645, groups:  ID_pianta, 478

Fixed effects:
                                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                         -2.946505   0.225251 -13.081  < 2e-16 ***
TrattamentoLavanda                  -0.367148   0.290348  -1.265  0.20605    
TrattamentoRosmarino                -0.229666   0.285925  -0.803  0.42184    
TrattamentoTimo                     -0.761728   0.306496  -2.485  0.01294 *  
Data_rilievo9                        0.109010   0.218369   0.499  0.61764    
Data_rilievo16                      -0.001370   0.218764  -0.006  0.99500    
Data_rilievo22                      -0.159518   0.230889  -0.691  0.48964    
Data_rilievo29                      -0.039270   0.223567  -0.176  0.86057    
Data_rilievo36                      -0.437104   0.227100  -1.925  0.05426 .  
Data_rilievo52                      -0.836964   0.234122  -3.575  0.00035 ***
Blocco2                             -0.293181   0.175388  -1.672  0.09460 .  
Blocco3                             -0.008417   0.173220  -0.049  0.96125    
TrattamentoLavanda:Data_rilievo9    -0.348587   0.333961  -1.044  0.29658    
TrattamentoRosmarino:Data_rilievo9  -0.135294   0.344371  -0.393  0.69441    
TrattamentoTimo:Data_rilievo9        0.217114   0.342126   0.635  0.52569    
TrattamentoLavanda:Data_rilievo16   -0.018477   0.326907  -0.057  0.95493    
TrattamentoRosmarino:Data_rilievo16 -0.365334   0.353116  -1.035  0.30086    
TrattamentoTimo:Data_rilievo16       0.307753   0.342737   0.898  0.36922    
TrattamentoLavanda:Data_rilievo22    0.021807   0.341696   0.064  0.94911    
TrattamentoRosmarino:Data_rilievo22 -0.220751   0.361474  -0.611  0.54140    
TrattamentoTimo:Data_rilievo22       1.006785   0.335352   3.002  0.00268 ** 
TrattamentoLavanda:Data_rilievo29   -0.069308   0.336851  -0.206  0.83698    
TrattamentoRosmarino:Data_rilievo29 -0.688504   0.378488  -1.819  0.06890 .  
TrattamentoTimo:Data_rilievo29       0.569437   0.337192   1.689  0.09127 .  
TrattamentoLavanda:Data_rilievo36    0.031248   0.348233   0.090  0.92850    
TrattamentoRosmarino:Data_rilievo36 -0.318984   0.379486  -0.841  0.40059    
TrattamentoTimo:Data_rilievo36       0.657741   0.349228   1.883  0.05964 .  
TrattamentoLavanda:Data_rilievo52   -0.043118   0.362352  -0.119  0.90528    
TrattamentoRosmarino:Data_rilievo52  0.176141   0.373717   0.471  0.63741    
TrattamentoTimo:Data_rilievo52       0.954141   0.345766   2.759  0.00579 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation matrix not shown by default, as p = 30 > 12.
Use print(x, correlation=TRUE)  or
    vcov(x)        if you need it
```

The results between **MODEL 1** and **MODEL 2** are quite different:

- **MODEL 1**: Lavanda and Rosmarino treatments, and some times are significant
- **MODEL 2**: Timo treatment and some Timo*Time are significant

Now, the question:

- Why the models report such different results?
- Which model shall I trust more? I am puzzled about which variables should be considered as fixed or random effects
- How to further check the validity of the model in terms of predictive capacities and residual analysis?

Comment: It may be more productive to formulate a model for your experimental data. (Once you have a model that fits the data well, you should be able to estimate the difference in proportion of infested leaves between conditions.) One model to consider is a [binomial GLM](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/232038/237901). (It can handle different number of leaves per data point but there is an assumption that the leaves in the same parcel are independent.)

Comment: Recent thread about a biological experiment that seems related and has some good advice: [What type of statistical tests can I use on this dataset?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/639072/237901)

Comment: @dipetkov thank you very much for the suggestion. Probably observations are not Independent since I have measures the same plants over time. How much strict is that assumption? Do you think I can go for a GLM in this case? Are there any alternative models that do not require Independent observations?

Comment: @dipetkov another issue. To use the GLM with binomial distribution I need that each row of my table is a single leave with a variable that tells me of the leave is infested or not. Correct? Currently my dataset is organized per plant (in a row I report the total number of leaves and the number of infested ones). I am not able to follow in time the infestation dynamics of the single leaves but just of the single plants.

Comment: Your data is aggregated: one row represents one experimental unit = plant, with two observations for each plant, number of infected leaves and number of leaves total. That format should work. Please take a look at the thread I linked above, esp. the part `cbind(number_of_dead_aphids, number_of_live_aphids)`. Also, if you are okay with posting the data on CV, that tends to help with getting on-point advice.

Comment: You need to replace NA with (presumably) 0 for the infested leaves, because right now all of those observations get ignored, leaving you with 806. Then you should also run the binomial model as @dipetkov explained. The `lme4`-function for a glmm is `glmer` .

Comment: @LukasLohse Ok. I edited the question. Thank you

Comment: Good progress! The question also mentions a blocking factor (which can be included in the model as a fixed effect) and a time factor. I'm not sure which column indicates the time. How many time points are there in the data?

Comment: @dipetkov thank you! I will make another edit. I will include the blocking factor as fixed effect. The time factor is the variable "Data_rilievo" which now is a random factor. I have seven points in time

Comment: I think that the model should have a fixed time effect. (Otherwise you want be able to compare the average treatment effects at the first sampling / the last sampling.)  One alternative is to include time as fixed `factor(Data_rilievo)`, which will take 6 degrees of freedom since there are 7 time points. (Another option is to include a spline of time. This would be more complex; the idea is to fit a flexible function for the time effect, not assume it's linear).

Comment: @dipetkov ok I will do that and edit the question. I used the following to treat Data_rilievo as factor: `data_infestate$Data_rilievo <- as.factor(data_infestate$Data_rilievo)
`

Comment: I should have suggested to include an interaction between treatment and time; without an interaction the pattern in time is the same for all the treatments. It might be interesting to compare the treatment-specific time effects. The pattern in the latest model indicates the effect is flat for the first 30 days and then drops off. (In this sense it would have been better to measure with more frequency in the second-half period). Also: I don't know much about DHARMa but to me the diagnostic plots don't indicate obvious issues.

Comment: The only reason you get those "deviations are significant" message is because you have so much data and the slightest deviation will become significant. I agree with the @dipetkov the plots don't indicate any obivous issues.

Comment: @dipetkov what about the scaled residuals? They should be simmetrical, correct? Can I still trust the model in my case?

`Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.7002 -0.4791 -0.3284  0.1969  4.6374`

Comment: @dipetkov @stefan when I add the interaction with time I get a message of no convergence of the model `Trattamento*Data_rilievo`

`Messaggio di avvertimento:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0294262 (tol = 0.002, component 1)`

I am not sure whether I can trust the model. If you think it is still ok, I can edit the question with the new model.

Using another dataset (with same variables) I get the same message with the current model (with no time nteraction). What to do in this case?

Comment: The scaled residuals reported by `summary(model_fit)` are not the dharma scaled residuals (these are between 0 and 1 -- notice the range in the two plots).

Comment: The convergence error may be tricky is solve without the data. There are many posts about such errors in convergence; perhaps take a look at some of that advice?

Comment: @dipetkov I solved the convergence error and edited the question. Now you will see that the results of the two models are quite different.

Comment: Great. Just noticed that you treat Block as numeric which doesn't sound right; it should be a factor right? I don't think staring at model coefficients and their significance is helpful. Once you have fitted a model, it's easier to use a package like emmeans or marginaleffects to study different aspects of the model. There are lots of CV posts how to use emmeans in particular. Take a look at some those and the vignettes.

Comment: And keep in mind that there is only so much advice you can get from just the summary output of a model fit. These last questions are really about how the analyze the data which can't really be done without the data.

Comment: I would say that in general you want to model block as a random effect since you are trying to account for block to block variation in the calculation of your expected values and are not really interested in whether or not block is “significant” or not. That being said when you do this you have to make sure to incorporate plant ID correctly. - (continued)

Comment: If plant is a unique number across all blocks then you can specify +(1|Block) + (1|Plant ID). If the ID’s however repeat within block, you want to either do +(1| Block/PlantID) or if you get convergence problems +(1|Block:PlantID). I would recommend you have a look here: https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html) and think through what you want to model.

Comment: @dipetkov thank you for the suggestion. Please, could you provide some more details on how to use emmeans to further study the model?

Comment: @Stefan plant is a unique number across blocks. Indeed, each plant incorporates the treatment_id and the block_id. So I think I can use the +(1|Block) solution

Comment: Check here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/index.html Under "Vignettes" there is a lot of great information on how to work with emmeans. The random effect could be +(1|Block) + (1|PlantID). Then if you get convergence problems, you could move it back into the fixed effects (as you currently have). You should also do this if your Block has less than 5 or 6 levels. This is all written in the GLMM FAQ I linked above,i.e. https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#should-i-treat-factor-xxx-as-fixed-or-random